# Ubuntu installer does not see external SSD

Tags: boot, hard-drive, ssd

I would like to install Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on my external SSD drive (internal HDD has Windows 10 installed on it).

Unfortunately, Ubuntu installation wizard does not see my external SSD - there are only SDA partitions visible. When I run `sudo fdisk -l` command I am able to see external SSD as sdb drive.

I tried to find similar topic, but found nothing.

Comment: Is the external drive already formatted? If so which file system? Is it by any chance NTFS and has been used with Windows?

Comment: @ChanganAuto, thanks for reply. This is brand new SSD, it was formatted with FAT32. I was creating bootable drive using Rufus.

Comment: What computer is it? 1.Please tell us more about it: brand name and model of the computer itself and 2. brand name and model of the graphics chip/card; 3. Please enter into your UEFI/BIOS menu system, and check, if you can select USB as an alternative for booting.

Comment: This is Toshiba Satellite L70-B-13H with Intel HD 4400 graphics chip. I already set USB with top priority in booting settings.

Comment: I have a Toshiba Satellite with an Intel i5 generation 3 CPU. I have used it a lot to test developing versions of Ubuntu and flavours (mainly Lubuntu), and that Toshiba has been quite user friendly, easy to boot and run with Ubuntu. I have often booted into external SSD drives, so I suspect it is not the computer's fault. It is possible that your adapter (or whatever interface) to the SSD drive is not quite compatible with the USB system of the computer, at least not seen by the boot system. I bought a couple of USB3 to SATA adapters before I found one that works well in most computers.

Comment: Hmm..but isnt it strange that I am able to boot the Ubuntu installation from this SSD disk without problems and when I choose "Try Ubuntu" instead of installation I am able to open command line and this external SSD is visible there.. This is WD Elements SE 1TB USB 3.0 drive, it is compatible with USB 2.0 and USB 3.0.

Comment: Yes, it is strange, but strange things happen when things are only 'almost compatible'. Maybe it it worth trying Lubuntu 22.04 LTS, which has another installer, Calamares (Ubuntu has Ubiquity). Or are you trying to install Ubuntu onto its own live drive? That will work only if you use the boot option `toram`, and it is risky, You can easily destroy your live drive without getting a working installed system.

Comment: Does this drive have encryption (Windows based) or security lock? Check manual. Also many, even new, SSD need firmware update.

Comment: From you comment, it sounds like you put the install media on the SSD, and are trying to then make a full installation there too.  The installer tries to avoid that situation, so maybe just put the ISO on a USB stick and you might then see the target SSD.

Comment: @ubfan1, thank you so much! That helped ;)

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, it sounds like you put the install media on the SSD, and are trying to then make a full installation there too. The installer tries to avoid that situation, so just put the ISO on a USB stick and you will then be able to see the target SSD.